# Location of Redis cache connection String in XC 9.2.0 PaaS Scaled

Tags: sitecore-commerce, azure, paas, redis

I have installed Sitecore 9.2.0 XC Scaled in Azure PasS. Hence there are two Redis cache has been created in azure portal, one for XC and one for XP.

I was able to find out where the Redis cache connection string is written for XP in the CD server. But nowhere I am getting where the Redis connection string is written for XC.

In the CM server, there was a connection string named "redis" and valued "session". But nowhere (not even in the connectionstring.config) I am getting the value of "session".

Main aim to find this out to use only one Redis cache by replacing the connections.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Redis configuration for XC in the config.json under *Caching/Redis*:

```
"Caching": {
  "Memory": {
    "Enabled": false,
    "CacheStoreName": "Commerce-Memory-Store"
  },
  "Redis": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "CacheStoreName": "Commerce-Redis-Store",
    "Options": {
      "Configuration": "localhost",
      "InstanceName": "Redis"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Which server it is? BizFx, CD, CM, Minions, Ops, Shops? 2. Need to access the connection string, not the config file.

Comment: The connect string is in the "Configuration" property. You will find this configuration and should adjust it for all XC services: Authoring, Minions, Ops and Shops.

Comment: See the documentation for further details: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/commerce-engine-caching.html